# How to use Hitechnic Color Sensor with ROS?

Tags: ros, nxt, nxt-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone provide an example of how to use Hitechnic NXT color sensor with ROS? We know how the RGB color sensor works but would like to know how to make the Hitechnic color sensor work with ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10535/how-to-use-hitechnic-color-sensor-with-ros?/) by [AutonomousRobots](https://answers.ros.org/users/807/autonomousrobots/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you will need to go into nxt-python and add the driver to work with the hitechnic color senor. then add the ROS binding to nxt_ros.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1